# Status_code 404 en consultas HTTP con Python en Google Colab

Tags: python, http, google-colab, 404

Creé una API con Java y Spring Boot con una ruta que, mediante una consulta GET, devuelve un string.
Cuando levanto el servidor en mi máquina local y hago la prueba con el browser y con Postman se conecta sin problemas en ambos casos y devuelve el string en el cuerpo de la respuesta como debe ser.
El problema se da cuando intento hacer la consulta mediante un código Python que escribí en Google Colab. Me devuelve un Status_ code 404. Intenté con varias librerías de Python ('requests', 'httplib', etc), y siempre me da un status 404 cuando la API no tiene problemas al consultar desde Postman o el mismo browser.
Tampoco es un problema de escribir mal la ruta HTTP, ya que lo verifiqué.
No sé si habrá un problema al hacer consultas a un servidor local desde Google Colab, y que por ello haya que realizar configuraciones especiales.